# Can you update the color of links in ::selection colored text?

Tags: css, hyperlink

CSS3 offers the new `::selection` filter, which lets you change the color of highlighted text.

```
::selection {
    color: #34495E;
}
```

However, sometimes the selection color contrasts badly with the default link color. I'd like to change the link color for highlighted text. I tried this:

```
::selection a {
    color: #222;
}
```

However this had no effect on the link color (in Chrome at least)

Is it possible to change the link color of selected text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the color of individual elements on selection. The correct syntax is, for example:

```
// Applied to the entire document
::selection,
::-moz-selection {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
}

// Applied only to <a> elements
a::selection,
a::-moz-selection
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Remember to include the vendor specific prefix in your CSS for Mozilla.

Comment: Odd. Chrome Developer Tools thought `::selection a` was a valid selector for the given element, except the link color didn't update. Clearly not the case.